# Where's old logs for apache gone, after updating macOS to Sierra

Tags: macos, apache, macos-sierra

I have updated macOS to Sierra, and old apache logs has gone.
Where I can find them?

Log directory was /var/log/apache2.
There are no old logs left, just new access/error logs are there.

Comment: Did you find them?

Comment: No, I couldn't find them. I guess they have been deleted by updater.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the new log directory appears to be in /private/var/log/apache2/